# Flex Advanceddatagrid scrollbar width

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I am using an `advanceddatagrid` in a Flex4.6 solution. I have two `advanceddatagrid`s that are placed on top of each other. At the moment I've got it to work so that moving the bottom horizontal scrollbar moves the top grids scrollbar accordingly but the problem is that it doesnt move it the same distance since one scrollbar is larger than the other. Does anyone know how to set the `horizontalscrollbar` width so that I can make them the same length?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some math:

```
grid2.horizontalScrollPosition = grid1.horizontalScrollPosition  * grid2.maxHorizontalScrollPosition/grid1.maxHorizontalScrollPosition;
```